# Copying only certain cells from a row to another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a workbook that has a large number of sheets designed to help my team manage their workload more efficiently.

When someone requests a job to be done, a row is added to a sheet called 'pending authorisation'

The team then have a drop down box on each row / record under column 'N' that is added and can either accept or decline the job.

If the team accepts the job, then it gets moved to another sheet called pending work, and deletes the record from the pending authorisation sheet.  The code that does this is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Sheets("Status Check").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Target.Value = "Accepted" Then
Rows(Target.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Pending Work").Rows(Lastrow)
Rows(Target.Row).Delete
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Although this works very well, I actually only want certain cells of this row to be copied over to the other worksheet rather than the entire row.  Is there any easy way to select only certain cells from each row to be copied over?

Comment: Use `Range("X" & Target.Row)` and copy to `Range("Y" & Lastrow)` (where `X` and `Y` and the source and target columns respectively)

Comment: Spot on yeah, that works, simple after I see how you've arrived at that answer, can I give you credit for the answer?

Comment: Did you set any criteria to access specific cells of the copied Row ?

Comment: You may try this also,,, `If cell.Value = "Accept" Then
      Range(Cells(cell.Row, "A"), Cells(cell.Row, "D")).Copy`

Comment: Other simplest method to copy conditionally/unconditionally should, `Target.Range("A13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("A5" & nxtRw)

Target.Range("I13:J13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("E5" & nxtRw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the entire row, you can copy from `Range("X" & Target.Row)` and to `Range("Y" & Lastrow)`

(where X and Y and the source and target columns respectively)